# How to intersect two rects in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, cgrect

I would like to remove the "blue" circle and just have a "hollow" center (so there's only the red layer and you can see the background inside). Filling the inside with the `clear` color doesn't work.

```
class AddButtonView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        // Outer circle
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        let outerPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
        outerPath.fill()

        // Center circle
        UIColor.blue.setFill()
        let centerRect = rect.insetBy(dx: rect.width * 0.55 / 2, dy: rect.height * 0.55 / 2)
        let centerPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: centerRect)
        centerPath.fill()
    }
}
```

How can I do it? `intersects` didn't do anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)

    // Outer circle
    UIColor.red.setFill()
    let outerPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
    outerPath.fill()

    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    context.saveGState()
    context.setBlendMode(.destinationOut)

    // Center circle
    UIColor.blue.setFill()
    let centerRect = rect.insetBy(dx: rect.width * 0.55 / 2, dy: rect.height * 0.55 / 2)
    let centerPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: centerRect)
    centerPath.fill()

    context.restoreGState()
}
```

Do not forget to give the view a `backgroundColor` of `.clear` and set its `isOpaque` property to `false`.

Inspired by [Draw transparent UIBezierPath line inside drawRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724906/draw-transparent-uibezierpath-line-inside-drawrect).

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: I'm sorry, this only adds a black background to the view. It does not solve my question.

Comment: Updated my answer with the result. Did you set the view's `backgroundColor` to `.clear`? And `isOpaque` to false?

Comment: Thanks, settings `isOpaque` to false did the trick! You may want to update your answer with that info.